# Incompatible JUnit tests with greenDAO

Tags: android, junit, greendao, greendao-generator

when I add greenDao Library in my proyect, my project doesn't work, because I have Junit test.

`testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile ('de.greenrobot:DaoGenerator:1.3.0')`

Any idea?

Comment: Comment out the tests, run/generate the code, then put the tests back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem, I change this

```
compile ('de.greenrobot:DaoGenerator:1.3.0')
```

to

```
compile('de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7')
```